# Suspected failed WD USB HDD shows in lsusb but not in lsblk. How can I get it to present as block level device?

Tags: 16.04, data-recovery

A friend of mine recently had a WD USB HDD stop mounting in Windows. I reproduced the issue in my Windows workstation, and plugged the drive in to a Lubuntu 16.04 PC that I use with other USB 3.0 HDDs. 
All I want to to is get the device to present itself as a block level device so I can get a raw disk image and work on recovering data from there out.

Syslog shows the device being connected, and the device appears under lsusb

```
 Bus 002 Device 005: ID 1058:25e2 Western Digital Technologies, Inc.
```

and here is the relevant part of syslog:

```
Apr 19 12:35:22 safe5 kernel: [ 9485.583924] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
Apr 19 12:35:23 safe5 kernel: [ 9486.939647] usb 2-7: new SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
Apr 19 12:35:23 safe5 kernel: [ 9486.960693] usb 2-7: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=25e2
Apr 19 12:35:23 safe5 kernel: [ 9486.960698] usb 2-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
Apr 19 12:35:23 safe5 kernel: [ 9486.960701] usb 2-7: Product: My Passport 25E2
Apr 19 12:35:23 safe5 kernel: [ 9486.960704] usb 2-7: Manufacturer: Western Digital
Apr 19 12:35:23 safe5 kernel: [ 9486.960706] usb 2-7: SerialNumber: 575837314431374E33335230
Apr 19 12:35:23 safe5 kernel: [ 9486.961519] usb-storage 2-7:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Apr 19 12:35:23 safe5 kernel: [ 9486.961653] scsi host6: usb-storage 2-7:1.0
Apr 19 12:35:23 safe5 mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 5: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-7"
Apr 19 12:35:23 safe5 mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 5 was not an MTP device
Apr 19 12:35:24 safe5 kernel: [ 9487.976221] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Passport 25E2 4004 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Apr 19 12:35:24 safe5 kernel: [ 9487.976545] scsi 6:0:0:1: CD-ROM            WD       Virtual CD 25E2  4004 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Apr 19 12:35:24 safe5 kernel: [ 9488.028070] scsi 6:0:0:2: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       4004 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Apr 19 12:35:24 safe5 kernel: [ 9488.064204] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
Apr 19 12:35:24 safe5 kernel: [ 9488.065447] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
Apr 19 12:35:24 safe5 kernel: [ 9488.065613] sr 6:0:0:1: [sr0] scsi3-mmc drive: 51x/51x caddy
Apr 19 12:35:24 safe5 kernel: [ 9488.065846] sr 6:0:0:1: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
Apr 19 12:35:24 safe5 kernel: [ 9488.065971] sr 6:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 5
Apr 19 12:35:24 safe5 kernel: [ 9488.066123] ses 6:0:0:2: Attached Enclosure device
Apr 19 12:35:24 safe5 kernel: [ 9488.066219] ses 6:0:0:2: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 13
Apr 19 12:35:24 safe5 kernel: [ 9488.067679] ses 6:0:0:2: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 1 got 8
Apr 19 12:35:24 safe5 kernel: [ 9488.067687] ses 6:0:0:2: Failed to get diagnostic page 0xffffffea
Apr 19 12:35:24 safe5 kernel: [ 9488.067692] ses 6:0:0:2: Failed to bind enclosure -19
Apr 19 12:35:26 safe5 com.canonical.indicator.application[1873]: (process:2050): indicator-application-service-WARNING **: Application already exists, re-req
uesting properties.
Apr 19 12:35:32 safe5 kernel: [ 9489.095572] .
Apr 19 12:35:34 safe5 kernel: [ 9496.007435] .
Apr 19 12:35:36 safe5 kernel: [ 9497.959602] .
Apr 19 12:35:38 safe5 kernel: [ 9499.911580] .
Apr 19 12:35:40 safe5 kernel: [ 9501.863560] .
Apr 19 12:35:42 safe5 kernel: [ 9503.815526] .
Apr 19 12:35:44 safe5 kernel: [ 9505.767521] .
Apr 19 12:35:46 safe5 kernel: [ 9507.719493] .
Apr 19 12:35:48 safe5 kernel: [ 9509.639304] .
Apr 19 12:35:50 safe5 kernel: [ 9511.591293] .
Apr 19 12:35:52 safe5 kernel: [ 9513.543421] .
Apr 19 12:35:54 safe5 kernel: [ 9515.495397] .
Apr 19 12:35:56 safe5 kernel: [ 9517.447378] .
Apr 19 12:35:58 safe5 kernel: [ 9519.399161] .
Apr 19 12:36:00 safe5 kernel: [ 9521.351332] .
Apr 19 12:36:02 safe5 kernel: [ 9523.303313] .
Apr 19 12:36:04 safe5 kernel: [ 9525.255294] .
Apr 19 12:36:06 safe5 kernel: [ 9527.207060] .
Apr 19 12:36:06 safe5 kernel: [ 9529.159242] .
Apr 19 12:36:06 safe5 kernel: [ 9529.279307] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Cannot set link state.
Apr 19 12:36:06 safe5 kernel: [ 9529.279317] usb usb2-port7: cannot disable (err = -32)
```

Comment: See if you can `chkdsk d: /f` on it in Windows. Change the d: to the appropriate drive designator.

Comment: Seems duplicate of [some of this answers](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=ses+2%3A0%3A0%3A1%3A+Wrong+diagnostic+page%3B+asked+for+1+got+8)